# Derby merge-statement results in "Insufficient data while reading from the network" error

Tags: sql, jdbc, merge, derby, apache-cocoon

We have an application (Apache Cocoon) that stores and retrieves data in an Apache Derby database. Derby is running in server mode, version is 10.12.1.1.

Queries, inserts and updates are executed without problems, but when a merge statement is executed, we get the error message "Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 21,272 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated."

Info in the Derby log.

```
Wed Jan 11 12:27:52 CET 2017 Thread[DRDAConnThread_5,5,main] (DATABASE = /appl2/derby/STEAD1_B2B_SCHEMA), (DRDAID = ��������.����-4326268907908754457{5}), Execution failed because of Permanent Agent Error: SVRCOD = 40; RDBNAM = /appl2/derby/STEAD1_B2B_SCHEMA; diagnostic msg = null
Wed Jan 11 12:27:52 CET 2017 : Execution failed because of Permanent Agent Error: SVRCOD = 40; RDBNAM = /appl2/derby/STEAD1_B2B_SCHEMA; diagnostic msg = null org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAProtocolException: Execution failed because of Permanent Agent Error: SVRCOD = 40; RDBNAM = /appl2/derby/STEAD1_B2B_SCHEMA; diagnostic msg = null at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAProtocolException.newAgentError(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.sendUnexpectedException(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.handleException(Unknown Source) at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)

Wed Jan 11 12:27:52 CET 2017 : null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DDMWriter.maxEncodedLength(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DDMWriter.writeString(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.writeSQLCAGRP(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.writeSQLCARD(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.writeSQLCARDs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

SQL merge-statement is:

```
merge into octl as trg
using octl_external as src
on (    trg.content_type = src.content_type
    and trg.distr_channel= src.distr_channel
    and trg.object_id    = src.object_id
    and trg.localisation = src.locale
    and trg.type         = src.type
    )
when not matched then
   insert ( content_type, distr_channel, object_id, localisation, type, masterlastmodified_ts, lastmodified_ts)
   values ( src.content_type, src.distr_channel, src.object_id, src.locale, src.type, src.lastmodified_ts, src.lastmodified_ts)
when matched then
   update set trg.masterlastmodified_ts = src.lastmodified_ts
            , trg.lastmodified_ts =  src.lastmodified_ts
```

This merge-statement was tested in the sql-console in Squirrel and works fine.

Summary: other sql-statements work fine from Cocoon, the merge statement works fine in Squirrel, but not from Cocoon.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Sure sounds like a bug. The merge statement is relatively new in Derby. Can you provide a minimal self-contained test case, and report it to the Derby developers at Apache?

Comment: The problem still exists 5 Years later in derby.

Comment: Bugreport: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-7134

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, we found two work-arounds:

1. passing the merge-statement to a Java stored procedure in Derby that
   executes the merge-statement.
2. replacing the merge-statement with an
   insert-where-not-exists statement and an update-where-exists
   statement.

We chose to go forward with the first approach, as it is more compact and executes faster.